# Android Studio 0.8.9: Created emulator with Google API 16, defaults to API 21

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to test on an older Android version on an emulator. I've worked a lot with them so this problem is frustrating me.

I created a new AVD with Google API 16 running Google ARMEABI. When I launch the emulator it starts up an AVD with API 21. I verified in the "About phone" that Android 5.0 is running on the emulator.

I have NOT explicitly created a 5.0 AVD. Why is this happening? Is the Google ARM actually ONLY for API 21?  If so why is it included in other API level SDKs?

I haven't uninstalled and reinstalled yet, seems like that's what I need to do but I'm wondering if anyone else is having this issue?

I can't paste images because I have no rep under this login, but I would if I could!

Comment: Regarding the images, you could upload them to tinypic.com or the like and provide a link to the images in your question.

Comment: Tried that, still didn't work, but found the answer by going through the file folders.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the SDK Manager is the culprit. It's listing the Google ARM as installable for earlier SDK versions when it's only actually used in API 21.

Unfortunately this means you can select it in the AVD Manager when creating an AVD that has an API lower than 21.